# Limit points of graphs

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If we don't use the metric topology definition, (a set is closed if it contains all of it's limit points), how do I tell that the sequence of points in infinitely many distinct edges is closed? Each singleton seems ok until near the vertex where they approach in this sequence.... how does it exactly intersect the closure of this edge in a closed set when there's no neighborhood's who else knows the answer to this one??????????

Comment: The definition of a closed set you've provided holds true in any space, not just metric topologies.

Comment: How if there's neighborhoods of points as in a metric topology is the set closed when all neighborhoods of the vertex contain a point from the edge, that means it's not closed !

Comment: If a set contains all of its limit points,  it is equal to its closure,  which by construction is closed. I don't understand your argument

Comment: @donthousand -How does this sequence contain all of its limit points when the vertex is a limit point? Unless it is not a limit point; can you show how it isn't then when there is a neighborhood of that point containing an element of the sequence telling me otherwise? thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the metric topology, one uses the weak topology. The weak topology is not the same as the metric topology, it has far more open subsets. This fact is the key to resolving your question.

To define the weak topology, first let me assume that the two endpoints of each edge are located at two different vertices of that edge, and therefore each edge $E$ is a closed arc, by which I mean that there exists a homeomorphism $f_E : E \to [0,1]$. The weak topology is defined so that a subset $U$ of the graph is open if and only if for each edge $E$, the set $f_E(U) \subset [0,1]$ is an open subset of the space $[0,1]$.

Now consider a sequence of distinct edges $E_1,E_2,...$.

Let $x_i \in \text{interior}(E_i)$ be any point (for $i=1,2,...$).

No matter what vertex $v$ you choose, $v$ **is not** a limit point of the sequence $x_i$. To prove that this is true, I shall construct an open subset $U$ of the graph that contains $v$ but does not contain any of the points $x_i$.

I'll construct $U$ in steps.

Step 1: Put $v \in U$.

Step 2: For each $i$, the point $x_i$ subdivides $E_i$ into two half-open arcs. Examine each of those half-open arcs to see if its endpoint equals $v$, and if so then put that entire subsegment in $U$.

Step 3: For every other edge $E$ not equal to any $E_i$, examine $E$ to see whether it has $v$ as one of its endpoints. If so then put the entire interior of $E$ in $U$, together with $v$ which is already in $U$.

By constructing $U$ as described, it is straightforward to see that $U$ is an open subset of the weak topology that contains $v$, but does not contain any $x_i$.